# How to increase waiting time for HttpClient request in angular 5?

Tags: angular

I am using HttpClient to make a sever call and wanted to wait until it respond back. This particular service call takes more than 2 minutes.
Following code only waits for 2 minutes even though I have added timeout of 3 minutes.

```
this.http.get('serverUrl')
.timeout(180000)
.catch(() => {
   return Observable.throw('Error');
});
```

I also tried implementing timeout with pipe operator. But this approach also timeout after 2 minutes of wait.

```
this.http.get('serverUrl')
.pipe(timeout(180000))
.catch(() => {
   return Observable.throw('Error');
});
```

Using timeout, I was able to decrease the service call waiting time but could not increase the waiting time.

I followed some of the previous posts regarding the similar problem, but those solutions did not work.

[Can't have a timeout of over 2 minutes with this.http.get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54186362/cant-have-a-timeout-of-over-2-minutes-with-this-http-get)

[Increase timeout in Angular 2+ and ASP.NET Core WebAPI application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55000027/increase-timeout-in-angular-2-and-asp-net-core-webapi-application)

The expectation is to increase the waiting time more than 2 minutes. I tested in Chrome and IE browser and found that service call using HttpClient is only waiting for 2 minutes for each service call.

Comment: `delay()` doesnt work? Hmm.. That is strange, it usually works fine for me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54187045/1956072t Already answers your question - **you can't**. Maybe you just didn't notice the answer. Sorry man.

Comment: So, there is no way of increasing 2 minutes timeout from angular HttpClient call.

Comment: @Antoniossss I have added that link in the post as well.

Comment: i know that, and comment is autogenerated. AND it answers your question