# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error when the server takes more than 2min to respond

Tags: node.js, express, http

I have written a web service using `node` & `express` that runs automation on request and responds with the finalized report.

I have used jquery `ajax` (tried `fetch` API as well) in the client side to start the automation in the server and on completion, reports are compressed as zip and sent to the client.

**Issue:**

When the server responds within 2 min, the zip is downloaded successfully but when the server takes more than 2 min to respond, the http request fails with "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" though there is no issue in the server side.
I learnt that by default there is no timeout for the HTTP requests but I am not sure why am I facing this issue.

I would like to know the reason behind this behavior.

Snippet of `ajax` request made in the client side:

```js
                var promise = $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost:8001/test',
                    method:'POST',
                    xhrFields: {
                        responseType: 'blob'
                    },
                    success: function(res){
                        downloadFromBlob(res);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, statusText, err){
                        alert(statusText);
                    },
                    data: options,
                });
```

Snippet from webservice (I have just tried to reproduce the issue here. The automation takes nearly 15 min to complete):

```
  router.get('/test/', runAutomation);
  async function runAutomation(req, res, next){
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
        const timeout = 120000;
        setTimeout(()=> {
            const path = 'reports.zip';
            res.download(path);
        }, timeout);
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In express, if we check **/bin/www** file content, by default it sets the timeout to **120000** ms as below

```
 server.setTimeout(120000);
```

We need to update it.
Ref: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_settimeout_msecs_callback

Answer (score 1):

This is caused not by the backend, but your browser - I have consistently seen the 2 minute timeout across all browsers at some point or another. You may want your backend to return a `202 Accepted` immediately, and ping it for updates rather than trying to wait for it to complete in one shot.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54187045/446747 also

Comment: But I have seen websites where the request takes like 10 min to respond but still, it doesn't fail and it completes without any error. How could that be? @josh.trow

Comment: It may take 10 minutes to send the full response, but it could be sending back little bits until then perhaps, keeping the browser waiting and restarting that 2 minute timeout?

Comment: No @josh.trow . I found that the issue is with the node server. Setting server.setTimeout(0) solved the problem. Thank you! You can refer here - https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_settimeout_msecs_callback. By default. the node server timeout is 2 min.